# Using openshift rhc tail command

Tags: openshift, error-log, openshift-client-tools

How do you tail openshift log files? I issued the following command:

```
rhc tail myapp
```

It seems to show first error line and then stops, but doesn't exit. If I press ctrl+C it asks whether to stop batch or not. How can I display last few errors and may be browse page by page? Is there page down/ page up shortcuts?

Answer (score 6):

The 'rhc tail' command reads the last few lines of each of your log files and continues to feed subsequent log messages to your console.  To view the entire log file, please review:
https://www.openshift.com/faq/how-to-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-logs

Comment: Went there but left wondering how to download them - I use notepad++ and I'd rather edit them locally - add that info there please (see my answer)

Answer (score 5):

you can see by running:

```
rhc tail -a yourappname -l youremail -p yourpassword
```

Comment: This works, but shows logs 'live'. Can be handy when something goes wrong; issue this command then execute the failing action and watch the logs as they are written. If you just want to browse log files, either ssh into the server and view logs there (using `cat`, `tail`, `grep`, `vi` etc) or (my personal favorite) configure FTP over ssh and just download the log files and open in your favorite editor.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `-a` option fix this issue for me.

```
rhc tail -a {app_name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Openshift place logs in different files, so if you want get logs of a specific file then you can add **-f file/address/and/name**

Example :

> **rhc tail -f app-root/logs/nodejs.log -a myAppName**

also you can ask for specific number of lines by adding **-o "-n 40"** in command. Above command will get last 40 lines.

Example :

> **rhc tail -f app-root/logs/nodejs.log -o "-n 40" -a myAppName**

Answer (score 0):

You can also download them:

```
$ scp  SHA@APP-DOMAIN.rhcloud.com:/var/lib/openshift/SHA/app-root/\
logs/APP.log "~/upstream.jbossas.log"
```

Feasible also in windows directly in git bash.