# Deploy Laravel application on OpenShift

Tags: php, git, laravel, openshift, web-deployment

I have `git push`ed my entire Laravel code base for the application that I had created on my `localhost` to my OpenShift server. But nothing seems to have come out of it. The webpage is still blank. Can someone tell me what changes to make to the application settings so that it gets deployed properly?

I have deployed it at [befikrin-befikrin.rhcloud.com](http://befikrin-befikrin.rhcloud.com).

Can someone please check and let me know what I might be doing wrong here?

While I was running the project on my `localhost` I has deployed it using:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

Do I need to do something on similar lines here?

**Update 1**

I tried fetching the logs with `rhc tail` but got the following message:

```
You can tail this application directly with:
ssh -t <MY_SSH_URL> 'tail */log*/*'
Could not parse PKey: no start line
Usage: rhc tail <application>
Pass '--help' to see the full list of options
```

Then I tried it with the `ssh -t...` command suggested above, and this time I got this:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Any help at this moment would go a great way as I have been trying to deploy it since yesterday with no avail.

Comment: Can you SSH to the server to see if the files are in place? Is your live site the target repository, or do you need to `pull` in the site directory to check out from the repo? Are there any errors in your Apache/PHP logs in your server? Is your web server vhost pointing to the `public/` folder?

Comment: (The `php -S` command is not a local deployment, by the way - it just starts up a development web server. No, this won't help on your remote host - you'll presumably be using Apache or NginX).

Comment: @halfer I `SSH`ed into the server and, to my knowledge all the files are in place. I don't understand the rest of your questions. I'm new to this thing. I've never deployed any application to any server. Can you put up the questions in greater detail?

Comment: Do you know where your server logs are? I think you're using Red Hat, but I've no experience of it, so I can only guess - perhaps `/var/log/apache2/error.log`? Search around there, and then try `tail <logpath>` to see what's at the end of it. There appears to be an extensive manual on the OpenShift site, so you could look through there to see if it notes where your log files are. Or you may have a control panel - again, just guessing.

Comment: @halfer Can you rather elaborate the steps that you follow during setting up your laravel application? What changes do you make, if any? Or do you just leave it as it is?

Comment: Find your error logs, please.

Comment: @halfer I tried fetching the logs with `rhc tail` but got the following message:

    `You can tail this application directly with:`
`ssh -t <MY_SSH_URL> 'tail */log*/*'`
    `Could not parse PKey: no start line`
    `Usage: rhc tail <application>`
    `Pass '--help' to see the full list of options`
Then I tried it with the `ssh -t...` command suggested above, and this time I got this:
    `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`
Any help at this moment would go a great way as I have been trying to deploy it since yesterday with no avail.

Comment: I am not familiar with `rhc` - is that provided by OpenShift, or is that standard on Red Hat installs? I was expecting you to SSH directly into the server, and to have a standard GNU/Linux shell (e.g. Bash) available to issue a `tail <file>` command (with no prefix).

Comment: Hmm, it looks like your [tail command is correct](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398550-I-get-a-500-internal-server-error-when-deploying-my-app). Maybe debug why this isn't working, then. Have you [searched for this error](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=openshift+php+error+log)? [Maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420798/using-openshift-rhc-tail-command).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laravel 5.0 and Laravel 4.2 QuickStarts exist for a reason. I STRONGLY recommend using them as a starting point for your Laravel application on OpenShift unless you're VERY familiar with both Laravel and OpenShift Online.

Deploy one of the QuickStarts below and port your existing application code over:

- Laravel 5: https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/115-laravel-5-0
- Laravel 4.2: https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/124-laravel-4-2

If you run into trouble [contact OpenShift](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) via our help site and mention @luciddreamz sent you in the comments.

Comment: I've deployed [lavarel 5](http://laravel5-igorsavinkin.rhcloud.com/home) into openshift and now it works well. Yet, how can I have an access to executing **artisan**?